# Very poor read performance compared to write performance on md(raid1) / crypt(luks) / lvm

Tags: performance, lvm, md

I'm experiencing very poor **read** performance over raid1/crypt/lvm. In the same time, write speeds are about 2x+ faster on the same setup. On another raid1 setup on the same machine I get normal read speeds (maybe because I'm not using cryptsetup).

OS related disks: sda + sdb. I have raid1 configuration with two disks, both are in place. I'm using LVM over the RAID. No encryption. Both disks are WD Green, 5400 rpm.

IO test results on this raid1:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output.img3 bs=8k count=256k conv=fsync
 - 2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 22.3392 s, 96.1 MB/s

sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
dd if=/tmp/output.img3 of=/dev/null bs=8k
 - 2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 15.9 s, 135 MB/s
```

And here is the problematic setup (on the same machine). Currently I have only one sdc (WD Green, 5400rpm) configured in software raid1 + crypt (luks, serpent-xts-plain) + lvm. Tomorrow I will attach another disk (sdd) to complete this two-disk raid1 setup.

IO tests results on this raid1:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=output.img3 bs=8k count=256k conv=fsync
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 17.7235 s, 121 MB/s

sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
dd if=output.img3 of=/dev/null bs=8k
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 36.2454 s, 59.2 MB/s
```

We can see that the read performance is very very bad (59MB/s compared to 135MB/s when using no encryption). Nothing is using the disks during benchmark. I can confirm this because I checked with iostat and dstat.

Details on the hardware:

- disks: all are WD green, 5400rpm, 64mb cache.
- cpu: FX-8350 at stock speed
- ram: 4x4GB at 1066Mhz.

Details on the software:

- OS: Debian Wheezy 7, amd64
- mdadm: v3.2.5 - 18th May 2012
- LVM version: 2.02.95(2) (2012-03-06)
- LVM Library version: 1.02.74 (2012-03-06)
- LVM Driver version:  4.22.0
- cryptsetup: 1.4.3

Here is how I configured the slow raid1+crypt+lvm setup:

parted /dev/sdc

1. mklabel gpt
2. type: ext4
3. start: 2048s
4. end: -1

Now the raid, crypt and the lvm configuration:

1. mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-disks=2 missing /dev/sdc
2. cryptsetup --cipher serpent-xts-plain luksFormat /dev/md1
3. cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md1 md1_crypt
4. vgcreate vg_sql /dev/mapper/md1_crypt
5. lvcreate -l 100%VG vg_sql -n lv_sql
6. mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg_sql-lv-sql
7. mount /dev/mapper/vg_sql-lv_sql /sql

So guys, can you help me identify the reason and fix it? It has to be something with the cryptsetup as there is no such read slowdown on the other setup (sda+sdb) where no encryption is present. But I have no idea what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: "Both disks are WD Green, 5400 rpm."
That'll be your problem.

Comment: I find it odd that WD Green drives are used but a power-hungry AMD is also used...

Comment: That's just like having a bowl of french fries, and loads of ketchup, because ketchup comes from tomatoes, and they're healthy, right?

Comment: @NathanC: I agree

Comment: @TomO'Connor: I don't expect these disks to be fast. What I expect is the crypted raid to be as fast on reading as the non-crypted raid.

Comment: @Android5360 It simply won't be faster. Serpent is one of the slowest algorithms you can select from LUKS.

Comment: `What I expect is the crypted raid to be as fast on reading as the non-crypted raid.`  Why?  Why would you expect that?

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork given that the encryption is usually slower than decryption, and that the CPU can do encryption with at least 121MB/s and the disk can read with at least 135MB/s I expect that the read (decryption) should be at least 121MB/s as this is >= 121 and <= 135.

Comment: @Android5360 Except that encryption (WRT symetric block ciphers) *isn't* slower than decryption.  They're mathematically equivalent operations, the same speed in each direction.  [You're seeing the impact of caches, buffers and seek times](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/38056/11622) - disk operations - not anything inherent in encryption of decryption (of symmetric block ciphers).

Comment: Drop the disks from the test, and instead use loop devices with backing files stored on tmpfs. Make them sufficiently small to fit in RAM, and sufficiently large to provide decent performance figures. That will allow you to benchmark the encryption/decryption portion of the equation without the performance of the HDDs interfering with the measurements.

Answer (score 2):

It should be obvious that encryption adds considerable overhead, but disregarding that:

You're also using non-AES encryption which means you don't get the acceleration from your processor (AES hardware acceleration). You're also using a desktop-quality processor *and* extremely slow consumer drives.

This setup is exactly why you're having such poor performance. Put decent drives in along with a server-quality processor (is this even a server?) and use AES for LUKS.

Comment: Regarding that: decryption usually is faster than encryption, isn't it?..

Comment: @poige Not always as it depends on caching. Unlike reads, writes are cached by the drive's controller and *reported* written when the drive doesn't have the data written to it yet. Reads are cached by the OS, but the OP dropped those caches before reading. Encryption/decryption are typically similar in speeds.

Comment: @poige Encryption is generally symetrical - equally fast in both directions.  If you're experiencing faster decryption than encryption, it's probably actually an issue of your disk read being faster than your disk write.

Comment: you guys awesome. http://serverfault.com/a/598838/67675

Comment: @poige Well, what does this have to do with OP's question?

Comment: If decryption is usually faster than encryption and this CPU can encrypt with at least 121MB/s and this disk can read with at least 135MB/s how can this configuration result in such bad read(decryption) performance?

Comment: @NathanC, thanks for asking. I think my answer has something more to it, than yours false attempt. )

Comment: @Android5360 See [this](http://www.storagereview.com/western_digital_caviar_green_2tb_review_wd20ears) for some benchmark data. It's a considerably slower drive than the faster cousins (WD Black, for example). Raid 1 is just a mirror, so performance isn't improved in this case.

Comment: @NathanC I agree that there are other faster drives than this one, but please note that I compare Green with Green and raid1 with raid1. So how your last comment helps? Or maybe I don't get it at all. If this is the case please correct me. Thank you guys for the time spent on this question.

Comment: "Raid 1 is just a mirror, so performance isn't improved in this case" again you're terribly wrong. OMG, study the subject before trying to teach others. http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelProjects/Raid1ReadBalancing

Comment: @poige How about you *read* what you posted before commenting with snide remarks, thanks. It's *not* implemented in Linux but it could be. Android, it's just a general statement. I'm not sure exactly *why* your performance seems backwards, but the configuration you gave certainly doesn't help.

Comment: @NathanC, lolwut? It's not implemented in Linux? =)) "RAID1 read balancing was added in 2.6.25: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=06386bbfd2441416875d0403d405c56822f6ebac" Oh, dude..

Answer (score 0):

It's usual not correctly done testing. Loading Linux Software RAID with 8k read operation is the way to ask it beahave poorly (you did). Try using larger `bs`.

---

I'm also adding this output of `cryptsetup benchmark` for ppl in comments below

```
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b   476.6 MiB/s  1891.3 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b    79.1 MiB/s   222.6 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b   135.0 MiB/s   158.7 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b   194.7 MiB/s   892.5 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   256b    46.2 MiB/s   211.4 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   256b   144.6 MiB/s    93.3 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b  1542.0 MiB/s  1727.0 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   256b   114.0 MiB/s   200.2 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   256b   111.4 MiB/s   131.7 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b   573.6 MiB/s   829.3 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   512b   199.8 MiB/s   191.1 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   512b    81.8 MiB/s   107.3 MiB/s
```

-- clearly seen (not always, but often) decryption is faster.

Comment: Wonderful that your system does this, that, or the other, but you're seriously misinformed about encryption at a fundamental level.  [Here's a good rundown of the reason for the apparent speed difference between decryption and encryption on symmetric block ciphers, like those being discussed in this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/38056/11622).

Comment: No chances for me to look at this since you've already tried explaining things using "caches". Thanks, I'm not buying. )

Comment: @HopelessN00b You are aware that the linked answer claims reading to be faster whereas this question is about reading being slower? Furthermore this seems a strange argument to me. Who would implement parallel execution **within** a drive sector instead of working on different sectors (or groups of sectors) in parallel?